# how to find the row number of similar strings

Tags: r

My data is huge but I want to know the row number of similar strings

```
df<- structure(list(x = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("AJ5ter2", 
"al-1Tter2", "AY9ter2", "CY-Yter2", "LK2ter2", "YY49ter2"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

a desire output is shown below

```
LK2ter2  1:4, 9:10
AJ5ter2  5:6
AY9ter2  7, 19
YY49ter2 10:11
al-1Tter2 12:15
CY-Yter2 16:18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `tidyverse` and `data.table` you can do:

```
df %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 group_by(x, rleid(x)) %>%
 summarise(res = ifelse(min(rowid) != max(rowid), 
                        paste(min(rowid), max(rowid), sep = ":"), paste(rowid))) %>%
 group_by(x) %>%
 summarise(res = paste(res, collapse = ", "))

  x         res     
  <fct>     <chr>   
1 AJ5ter2   5:6     
2 al-1Tter2 12:15   
3 AY9ter2   7, 19   
4 CY-Yter2  16:18   
5 LK2ter2   1:4, 8:9
6 YY49ter2  10:11
```

Or the same with just `tidyverse`:

```
df %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 group_by(x, x_rleid = {x_rleid = rle(as.numeric(x)); rep(seq_along(x_rleid$lengths), x_rleid$lengths)}) %>%
 summarise(res = ifelse(min(rowid) != max(rowid), 
                        paste(min(rowid), max(rowid), sep = ":"), paste(rowid))) %>%
 group_by(x) %>%
 summarise(res = paste(res, collapse = ", "))
```

Both codes, first, add a column with row ID. Second, they group by "x" and the run-length group ID of "x". Third, they assess whether the minimum row ID is equal to maximum row ID. If not, they combine the value of minimum and maximum row ID, separated by `:`, otherwise use just a single row ID value. Finally, they group by just "x" and combines the different elements by `,`.

Or if you want all the values, not just the ranges:

```
df %>%
 rowid_to_column() %>%
 group_by(x, x_rleid = {x_rleid = rle(as.numeric(x)); rep(seq_along(x_rleid$lengths), x_rleid$lengths)}) %>%
 summarise(res = paste(rowid, collapse = ",")) %>%
 group_by(x) %>%
 summarise(res = paste(res, collapse = ","))

  x         res        
  <fct>     <chr>      
1 AJ5ter2   5,6        
2 al-1Tter2 12,13,14,15
3 AY9ter2   7,19       
4 CY-Yter2  16,17,18   
5 LK2ter2   1,2,3,4,8,9
6 YY49ter2  10,11
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
DT <- as.data.table(df)
DT[, .(index = paste(unique(range(.I)), collapse = ":")), by = .(x, rleid(x))
   ][, .(index = toString(index)), by = x]
#           x    index
#1:   LK2ter2 1:4, 8:9
#2:   AJ5ter2      5:6
#3:   AY9ter2    7, 19
#4:  YY49ter2    10:11
#5: al-1Tter2    12:15
#6:  CY-Yter2    16:18
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like:

```
z <- sapply(levels(df$x), function(x) which(x == df$x))
data.frame(key = names(z), index = sapply(z, paste, collapse = ", "), row.names = NULL)

        key            index
1   AJ5ter2             5, 6
2 al-1Tter2   12, 13, 14, 15
3   AY9ter2            7, 19
4  CY-Yter2       16, 17, 18
5   LK2ter2 1, 2, 3, 4, 8, 9
6  YY49ter2           10, 11
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way with `dplyr` methods. Not sure if you want text output or a numeric vector

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- structure(list(x = structure(c(5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("AJ5ter2", "al-1Tter2", "AY9ter2", "CY-Yter2", "LK2ter2", "YY49ter2"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))
df %>%
  mutate(row_number = row_number()) %>%
  group_by(x) %>%
  summarise(row_nums = str_c(row_number, collapse = ","))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 2
#>   x         row_nums   
#>   <fct>     <chr>      
#> 1 AJ5ter2   5,6        
#> 2 al-1Tter2 12,13,14,15
#> 3 AY9ter2   7,19       
#> 4 CY-Yter2  16,17,18   
#> 5 LK2ter2   1,2,3,4,8,9
#> 6 YY49ter2  10,11
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Beat me to it;-) perhaps slightly more succinct: `rowid_to_column("row_number")` instead of `mutate(row_number = row_number())`, and `toString(...)` instead of `str_c(..., collapse = ",")`.